# Laravel logs out authenticated user on redirect in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have reviewed all the session settings, but it still doesn't work on the server, but locally it works. I don't know if it's relevant, but it doesn't save cookies, not even from the csrf token

Laravel version: 9.52.10
PHP version: PHP 8.1

routes/web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Backend\BackendController;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


// Auth Routes
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::get('/', function () {
    if (auth()->user()->hasRole('employee')) {
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_REDIRECT);
    } else {
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
})->middleware('auth');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'app', 'middleware' => 'role:admin|manager'], function () {

    
    Route::group(['as' => 'backend.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

        /**
         * Backend Dashboard
         * Namespaces indicate folder structure.
         */
        Route::get('/', [BackendController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    });
});
```

route/auth.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// Check if registration is enabled
if (user_registration()) {
    Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
        Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
            ->name('register');

        Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);
    });
}

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('password.request');

    Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('password.email');

    Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
        ->name('password.reset');

    Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('password.update');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
        ->name('logout');
});
```

AuthenticatedSessionController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Trait\AuthTrait;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    use AuthTrait;

    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $isLogin = $this->loginTrait($request);

        if ($isLogin) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

AuthTrait.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Trait;

use App\Events\Auth\UserLoginSuccess;
use App\Events\Frontend\UserRegistered;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;

trait AuthTrait
{
    protected function loginTrait($request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;
        $remember = $request->remember_me;

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1], $remember)) {
            event(new UserLoginSuccess($request, auth()->user()));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function registerTrait($request, $model = null)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:191'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:191'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:191', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            'gender' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $arr = [
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'name' => $request->first_name . ' ' . $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'mobile' => $request->mobile,
            'gender' => $request->gender,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ];

        $user = User::create($arr);

        $user->syncRoles(['user']);

        \Artisan::call('cache:clear');

        $user->save();

        event(new Registered($user));
        event(new UserRegistered($user));

        return $user;
    }
}
```

That allows the user to log in as it does in the localhost